# Chef - use env variable with package resource what created with bash resource

Tags: ruby, bash, git, chef-infra

I would get the changed project from git commit and install the package based on this.
Here is my code

```rb
bash 'get_project' do
  code <<-EOH
  filelist=$(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $1)
  for file in ${filelist[@]}; do
    project=$(echo $file | cut -d "/" -f1)
    projectList+=($project)
  done
  for changedProject in $(echo "${projectList[@]}" | sort | uniq); do
    INSTALLABLE_RPM=application-$changedProject
  done
  EOH
  environment 'INSTALLABLE_RPM' => '$INSTALLABLE_RPM'
end

zypper_package ENV['INSTALLABLE_RPM']
```

My idea is to generate the `INSTALLABLE_RPM` variable with bash and install the package with zypper. Unfortunately it doesn't work. The zypper_package resource cant recognize.

I ran out of ideas :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `environment` property of the [bash resource](https://docs.chef.io/resources/bash/) is to supply *existing* environment variables to execute the bash command(s).

> (These variables must exist for a command to be run successfully.)

Specifying environment variables here will not set them in the shell. Also from within the `code` block you will not be able to access the Ruby's `ENV` hash.

There may not be a straight-forward way to do this. One of the options is to write this package (list?) to a file. Then we can read the file contents into variable, and use it with `zypper_package` resource.

Example:

Since you have used `for` loop in Shell, I believe you get a list of packages, so I am considering `pkg_list` as Array. I've set `compile_time` to `true` as the variable assignment below `bash` resource will *only* run during compile time.

```rb
bash 'get_project' do
  code <<-EOH
  # your code as-it-is
  for changedProject in $(echo "${projectList[@]}" | sort | uniq); do
    echo "application-$changedProject" >> /tmp/rpm_packages
  done
  EOH
  compile_time true
end

pkg_list = File.read('/tmp/rpm_packages').split

zypper_package pkg_list

# remove the file for good measure :)
file '/tmp/rpm_packages' do
  action :delete
end
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. You mean If I pre-define the env var I can pass through?
Basically I'm using GitlabCI, so if I define the INSTALLABLE_RPM in the .gitlab-ci could it works?

Comment: Yes, if you can get this environment variable defined outside Chef, then you can install it with `zypper_package ENV['INSTALLABLE_RPM']`. Defining this variable by running code inside Chef recipe is little tricky.

Comment: I mean define the env variable outside from chef ( in gitlab-ci ) but fill it with the bash resource and install it with the package resource. bash an package resource in the same recipie

Comment: From `bash` resource we cannot set environment variables. So set environment variable before starting the Chef recipe. In the Chef recipe, there will be code only to install package.

Comment: Meanwhile I found a gitlab setup what might help to me but it doesnt work well. do you know the artifacts:reports:dotenv job artifact?
WARNING: package.env: no matching files            
ERROR: No files to upload

Comment: I am not that well versed with Gitlab so I am not sure how to address this issue.